# Variable undefined inside of set timeout

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, settimeout

Why is the eta variable undefined after 1st interation? I looked in Closures, Invokable Functions, Binding but im not sure what the deal is...

```js
var eta = 5400

function runCode() {
  function queryEta(eta) {
    // redo the eta lol
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(eta)
      queryEta()
    }, eta);
  }

  queryEta(eta);
}

runCode()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redefining what the `eta` variable means inside the function when you create a locally-scoped parameter with the same name.

Also, don't forget to pass the parameter to the function call inside the inner function.

If you are having trouble understanding scoping, check out a tutorial e.g. ["JavaScript Scope and Closures"](https://css-tricks.com/javascript-scope-closures/).

```js
var globalEta = 5400;

function runCode() {
  function queryEta(localEta) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(localEta)
      queryEta(localEta); // Make sure you pass this in!
    }, localEta);
  }

  queryEta(globalEta);
}

runCode()
```

You could access the window...

```js
var eta = 5400;

function runCode() {
  function queryEta(eta) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(eta)
      queryEta(eta); // Make sure you pass this in!
    }, eta);
  }

  queryEta(window.eta); // Here!
}

runCode()
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call `queryEta()` without any arguments the `eta` argument inside `queryEta` is undefined (and shadows the one defined at the top)